# EXC_BAD_ACESS when IBAction button is clicked

Tags: objective-c, xcode

i ve got an IBACtion button when the button is clicked.it got to open a new view.when the button is clicked i m getting EXC_BAD_ACCESS.i ve enabled NSZOMBIE and it shows the last line in the function -(void)homepage could u guys help me out..below is the code.

splashscreen.h

```
@interface SplashScreen : UIViewController {
HomePage *newEnterNameController;
}

 @property(nonatomic,retain)HomePage *newEnterNameController;
 @end
```

splashscreen.m

```
    @implementation SplashScreen
    @synthesize newEnterNameController;


      -(void)homepage
       {
    self.newEnterNameController = [[HomePage new] initWithNibName:@"HomePage"bundle: 
       [NSBundle mainBundle]];
        [newEnterNameController setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal];
    [self presentModalViewController:self.newEnterNameController animated:YES];
     }

    - (void)dealloc {
    [self.newEnterNameController release];
       [super dealloc];

      }


@end
```

Comment: In the first statement in the `homepage` method, you want `alloc` instead of `new` and you need to add an `autorelease` message to avoid  leaking resulting in: `self.newEnterNameController = [[[HomePage alloc] initWithNibName:@"HomePage"bundle: 
   [NSBundle mainBundle]] autorelease];`

Comment: cud u gimme a small example of how this can be done.

Comment: `[self presentModalViewController:self.snewEnterNameController animated:YES];` could you please fix this typo (`self.*s*new...`)

Comment: Try to write "backtrace" in the console, and see exactly what is the code that is crashing the application, and if possible post the backtrace response here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
self.newEnterNameController = [[HomePage new] initWithNibName:@"HomePage"bundle:    [NSBundle mainBundle]];
```

`[Class new]` is equal to `[[Class alloc] init]`, so you are initializing object twice. This line should probably look like this:

```
self.newEnterNameController = [[HomePage alloc] initWithNibName:@"HomePage"bundle:    [NSBundle mainBundle]];
```

Comment: i figured the problem its home page view that is opened in modal view

Answer (score 0):

replace   -(void)homepage with   -(IBAction)homepage:(id)sender, and relink the button from interface builder,or programatically depending on your UIButton creation code

Answer (score 0):

instead of this:

```
-(void)homepage
   {
self.newEnterNameController = [[HomePage new] initWithNibName:@"HomePage"bundle: 
   [NSBundle mainBundle]];
    [newEnterNameController setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal];
[self presentModalViewController:self.snewEnterNameController animated:YES];
 }
```

try as:

```
-(IBAction)homepage
   {
self.newEnterNameController = [[[HomePage alloc] initWithNibName:@"HomePage"bundle: 
   [NSBundle mainBundle]]autorelease];
    [newEnterNameController setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal];
[self presentModalViewController:self.snewEnterNameController animated:YES];
 }
```

and connect this to your button in interface builder.Now see the result.